# Xamarin Android EggsToGo (swipe gesture) listener in view doesnt work with ListView

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, listener

I have a problem with EggsToGo (swipe left/right effect) listener in a ListView control. I had problem [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049130/xamarin-android-scrollview-doesnt-work-in-listview) and found the problem with EggsToGo exactly with a ListView listener... when I have a listener on my ListView so the ScrollView doesnt work there.... Is there some solution how I can make EggsToGo listener on view that will work on ListView?

My test project is [HERE](https://github.com/pinkysek/XabluDemoApp) - the problem is in the FirstFragment (First view). When I have a listener on listview, the scrollview doesnt work. But when I don't have a listener, the swipe doesn't work....

**Here is code my view:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_back_layout" />
<!-- Test Top Layout -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/view_shopname_lastupdate_ribbon" />
<!-- Layout Date and Picker-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Období:"
            local:MvxLang="Text Period"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textColor="@color/main_dark_gray"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        <MvxSpinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/periodSpinner"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource PeriodList; SelectedItem SelectedPeriod"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
             <oxyplot.xamarin.android.PlotView
               android:id="@+id/dailySalesModel"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:background="@android:color/white" />
             <MvxListView
              android:id="@+id/dailySalesListView"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              local:MvxBind="ItemsSource DailySales"
              local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/view_dailysalesitem"
              android:divider="@color/main_gray"
              android:dividerHeight="1dp"
              android:choiceMode="none"
              android:layout_gravity="start"
              android:background="@android:color/white"
              android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
              android:paddingTop="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <include
            layout="@layout/view_bottomribbon" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is code my fragment:**

```
   [MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, true)]
    public class DailySalesFragment : BaseBackFragment<DailySalesViewModel>, View.IOnTouchListener
    {
        private Easter _easter;
        private View _view;
        protected override int FragmentId => Resource.Layout.fragment_dailysales;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            _view = this.BindingInflate(FragmentId, null);

            var orientation = Resources.Configuration.Orientation;

            if (orientation == Orientation.Landscape)
            {
                var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;

                var height = CoreHelper.ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.HeightPixels, Resources);

                if (height <= 360)
                {
                    var topLayout = _view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.topLayout);
                    if (topLayout != null)
                    {
                        topLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                    }
                }
            }

            var plotView = _view.FindViewById<PlotView>(Resource.Id.dailySalesModel);
            var bindset = this.CreateBindingSet<DailySalesFragment, DailySalesViewModel>();
            bindset.Bind(plotView).For(q => q.Model).To(vm => vm.Model);
            bindset.Apply();

            _easter = new Easter(new KonamiCode());

            var easyEgg = new CustomEgg("Easy")
                .WatchForSequence(Command.SwipeLeft(), Command.SwipeRight());

            _easter = new Easter(easyEgg);
            _easter.CommandDetected += cmd => DoSwipe(cmd.Value);

            var model = _view.FindViewById<PlotView>(Resource.Id.dailySalesModel);
            var listView = _view.FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.dailySalesListView);
            model?.SetOnTouchListener(this);
            listView?.SetOnTouchListener(this);

            InitializeSwipeButtons();
            InitializeShopPicker();

            return _view;
        }

        public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
        {
            base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            ViewModel.RefreshView();
        }

        private void InitializeShopPicker()
        {
            var shopLayout = _view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.shopLayout);
            if (shopLayout != null)
            {
                shopLayout.Click += delegate
                {
                    ShowShopPickerDialog();
                };
            }
        }

        private void ShowShopPickerDialog()
        {
            var dialog = new ShopPickerDialogFragment(ViewModel.ShopId);
            dialog.DialogClosed += OnDialogClosed;
            dialog.Show(this.Activity.FragmentManager, null);
        }

        private async void OnDialogClosed(object sender, Helpers.ShopPickerDialogEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsChanged)
            {
                var shop = e.Shop;
                await ViewModel.ChangeShop(shop);
            }
        }

        private void InitializeSwipeButtons()
        {
            var leftButton = _view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.leftButton);
            if (leftButton != null)
            {
                leftButton.Click += delegate
                {
                    DoSwipe("RIGHT");
                };
            }

            var rightButton = _view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.rightButton);
            if (rightButton != null)
            {
                rightButton.Click += delegate
                {
                    DoSwipe("LEFT");
                };
            }
        }

        private void DoSwipe(string swipeText)
        {
            if (swipeText.Equals("LEFT"))
            {
                FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                    .SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.slide_from_right, Resource.Animation.slide_to_left)
                    .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, GroupSalesFragment.NewInstance(null))
                    .Commit();
            }

            if (swipeText.Equals("RIGHT"))
            {
                FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                    .SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.slide_from_left, Resource.Animation.slide_to_right)
                    .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, ReportsFragment.NewInstance(null))
                    .Commit();
            }

            ViewModel.SwipeView(swipeText);
        }

        private int ConvertDpToPixels(int dp)
        {
            var pixels = dp * Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
            return (int)pixels;
        }

        private void RefreshLayout(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += WorkerDoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerCompleted;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void WorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            _dailySalesSwipeRefreshLayout.Refreshing = false;
        }

        private void WorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(ViewModel.ExecuteRefreshAsync);
        }

        public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            _easter.OnTouchEvent(e);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Edit - test project github link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I have a listener on listview, the scrollview doesnt work. But when I don't have a listener, the swipe doesn't work

It has something wrong with `Easter`'s `OnTouch` method, I dont know its logic but you could do it by yourself in `OnTouch` to implement this feature.

You could use `SetOnTouchListener` method for your whole `FirstFragment` layout,  and implement your logic in your `OnTouch` method, here is my code :

```
var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
......
view.SetOnTouchListener(this);
//model?.SetOnTouchListener(this);
//listView?.SetOnTouchListener(this);

float mPosX = 0;
float mCurPosX = 0;
float mPosY = 0;
float mCurPosY = 0;
public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
       case MotionEventActions.Down:
            mPosX = e.GetX();
            mCurPosX = mPosX;
            mPosY = e.GetY();
            mCurPosY = mPosY;
            break;
       case MotionEventActions.Move:
            mCurPosX = e.GetX();
            mCurPosY = e.GetY();

            float xDistance = Math.Abs(mCurPosX - mPosX);
            float yDistance = Math.Abs(mCurPosY - mPosY);
            if (xDistance > yDistance && mCurPosX - mPosX > 0)//Swip Right
            {
                DoSwipe("RIGHT");
            }
            else if (xDistance > yDistance && mCurPosX - mPosX < 0)//Swip Left
            {
                DoSwipe("LEFT");
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Effect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6iAG.gif).

Comment: ye... It works rly well... thank you so much... sorry for my late answer

Comment: hmm weird is when I tried this in my test project it works well.... but when I using it in main project it works but my swipe animations to left/right doesnt works... and in my test project animations works :D

Comment: but when I used view.SetOnTouchListener(this); with EggsToGo it works

Comment: but still when is view clear and there is one clear linearLayout its works well, but when I have in view some more linearLayout with something listener is sometimes rly weird

Comment: @pnk, when you used `view.SetOnTouchListener(this)`, the `EggsToGo` did work, but it stopped `ListView` response for the ouch event.

Comment: is any solution how to make ListView working with Swipe? In my view react all on swipe but ListView not...

Comment: @pnk, you could custom a `ListView` and override its `OnTouchEvent`method  to implement this feature.